# PrimeFaces lazydatamodel load method not called from second time onwords

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have dynamic tabs... 
as most of the columns are same I wrote custom component to show the table in tabs.

When I clicked on each tab it's respectve lazy datamodel load method is called.. after multiple switch of tabs if I click on the tab the load method is not called... so showing old data... not fetching from database.

I want load() method to be called every time. I mean if I click on tab it's data model load() method should be called..

How to do it?

Here is my code:

```
<p:tabView id="vzTabView" styleClass="vzTabView" dynamic="true"  >

        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean1.onTabChange}" process="@this"  />

        <c:forEach items="#{bean1.values}" var="tab">

                <p:tab id="#{tab.uniqueTabId}s" title="#{tab.label}" rendered="#{bean1.isSteeringListRendered(tab)}">
                    <h:form id="#{tab.uniqueTabId}s-Form" onkeyup="avoidEnter(event)">  
                            // custom component         
                        <pc:pcData id="id1" gridId="grid1" bean="#{bean2}" isCostumer ="false"/>                    
                    </h:form>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="#{tab.uniqueTabId}c" title="#{tab.label}" rendered="#{bean1.isCostumerListRendered(tab)}">
                    <h:form id="#{tab.uniqueTabId}c-Form" onkeyup="avoidEnter(event)" > 

                        <pc:pcData id="id2" gridId="grid2" bean="#{bean3}" isCostumer ="true"/>                 
                    </h:form>
                </p:tab>

        </c:forEach>
    </p:tabView>
```

// Custom component

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="bean" />
    <cc:attribute name="gridId" />
    <cc:attribute name="isCostumer" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

        <p:dataTable id="${cc.attrs.gridId}" editMode="cell" var="row" 
            selectionMode="single" paginator="true"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="20,50,100,150,200"
            paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            currentPageReportTemplate="({currentPage} #{msgs.of} {totalPages})"
            value="#{cc.attrs.bean.lazyDataModel}" lazy="true"
            rowKey="#{row.id}" editable="true" rows="20" styleClass="pst-grid">
                ....
                .....
                </p:datatable>
```

I tried with remoteCommand trick after tab click, by updating the table still no luck.

Comment: Does it work when you don't use a composite component?

Comment: Does it work when you don't use a composite component?

Comment: Hi Kukeltje, I am not using composite component

Comment: You are, but you call it custom component in your post!!! https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen

Comment: ok, you mean csutom component, Yes, I used..... But, I have to use custom component for my use case....

Comment: When I use cache="false" , tab is showing empty ... but as per the documentation.. " tab contents are reloaded from server each time tab is clicked.  "

Comment: TRY without one. Does it make difference? No then it is not related to the **composite** component and you narrowed down the problem. Does putting a simple plain outputText get reloaded each time?